# is native C++ code that uses serialization portable to WebAssembly?

Tags: c++, web, webassembly, emscripten

Recently I have decided to use web for GUI in my app's client and therefore I have faced a question of communicating between native code and JS.
Another option I began to consider is porting C++ code to WebAssembly (which I am completely unfamiliar with). It would be rather handy to have a possibility to compile the client C++ code both to native and to Wasm without the need to modify much of it, in case I will be required to make a pure native application. I don't know the limitations for such portability, except for needing 3rdparty libraries to have a ported version.

So, one of the problems:
my native C++ client among other things communicates with different devices via various custom protocols. For example, I have a protocol for a joystick. I receive a byte array via serial port and cast it to a protocol struct via `reinterpret_cast` (using `std::copy` to avoid UB):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

    /*!
     * \brief Data structure for deserialization of a received message from Joystick
     */
    struct JoyL410FData
    {
        constexpr static uint8_t header[] = {0x68, 0x9B};

        uint8_t id;        
        uint8_t id2;       
        uint8_t VerLo;        
        uint8_t VerHi;        

        uint16_t function: 1,     
        dispSwitch: 4, 
        zero: 1,        
        diskrZoom: 4,        
        distance: 1,        
        analogZoom: 2,        
        modeSelect: 1,        
        freezeFrame: 1,        
        reserve: 1;        
        uint16_t inversBit;
        int16_t x;                           
        int16_t y;                           
        uint16_t crc16;                        
        void setVersion(uint8_t AVerLo, uint8_t AVerHi)
        {
            VerLo = AVerLo;
            VerHi = AVerHi;
        }

        void clear()
        {
            std::memset((uint8_t *) this + 3, 0, sizeof(JoyL410FData) - 3);
        }
    };
```

Example for receiving data.

```
    // this line is just for abstraction
    std::vector<uint8_t> receivedArray = receive();
    JoyL410FData data{};
    std::copy(receivedArray.cbegin(), receivedArray.cend(), reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&data));
```

1. Is this code portable to WebAssembly?
2. What about endianness?
3. Will this result in a noticeable drop of performance?

Comment: Point 2 is directly related to point 1 since reinterpret_cast is not portable due to endianness. A reinterpret_cast itself is done at compile time. With drop of performance, what exactly do you mean or in comparison to what? The original uint8 plain data transfer?